# Regular Expression to extract Shipping Cost

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
string str = "var rawItemInfo={\"stock\":\"In stock. Limit 5 per customer.\",\"shipping\":\"$19.99 Shipping\",\"finalPrice\":\"139.99\",\"itemInfo\":\"<div class=\"grpPricing\"";
var regPattern = "stock\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?shipping\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?finalPrice\":\"(.*?)\"";
Regex regex = new Regex(regPattern);
var data = regex.Match(str);

string val1 = data.Groups[1].Value.ToString();  // In stock. Limit 5 per customer.
string val2 = data.Groups[2].Value.ToString();  // $19.99 Shipping
string val3 = data.Groups[3].Value.ToString();  // 139.99
```

How can I edit the regular expression to extract `19.99` from shipping? Currently, it is giving me "`$19.99 Shipping`". Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Remember! Shipping can be like this too `"shipping\":\"free Shipping\"`

Comment: You cheated changing the rules!

Comment: lolz i forgot to write bcz i saw i m getting this value too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regPattern = "stock\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?shipping\":\"(?:(?:\\$([0-9]*\\.[0-9]*)|(free Shipping)).*?)\",\".*?finalPrice\":\"(.*?)\"";

string val1 = data.Groups[1].Value.ToString();  // In stock. Limit 5 per customer.
string val2 = data.Groups[2].Value.ToString();  // 19.99 
string val3 = data.Groups[3].Value.ToString();  // free Shipping            
string val4 = data.Groups[4].Value.ToString();  // 139.99
```

Only one of val2 and val3 will be valorized (the other will be String.Empty)

This if your shipping will always be 123.456 (so there will always be some numbers BEFORE the . and some numbers AFTER the .)

Comment: Remember! Shipping can be like this too `"shipping\":\"free Shipping\"`

Comment: your solution giving "" empty result

Comment: @SOF Changed. Problem with cut-n-paste

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

Had some trouble with both cut'n'paste and some other technical difficulties (namely lack of caffeine--extended "two-thirty feeling"). Here's the solution, in its entirety:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                String s = "var rawItemInfo={\"stock\":\"In stock. Limit 5 per customer.\",\"shipping\":\"$19.99 Shipping\",\"finalPrice\":\"139.99\",\"itemInfo\":\"<div class=\"grpPricing\"";
                Console.WriteLine("Testing '{0}'", s);
                test(s);

                Console.WriteLine();

                s = "var rawItemInfo={\"stock\":\"In stock. Limit 5 per customer.\",\"shipping\":\"free Shipping\",\"finalPrice\":\"139.99\",\"itemInfo\":\"<div class=\"grpPricing\"";
                Console.WriteLine("Testing '{0}'", s);
                test(s);
        }

        public static void test(String s)
        {
                String p = "stock\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?shipping\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?finalPrice\":\"(.*?)\"";
                // modification
                p = "stock\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?shipping\":\"(\\$([\\d\\.]+)|(free))\\s?(.*?)\",\".*?finalPrice\":\"(.*?)\"";

                Regex regex = new Regex(p);
                var data = regex.Match(s);

                for (Int32 i = 0; i < data.Groups.Count; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1}", i, data.Groups[i].Value);

                Console.WriteLine("Price is {0}", data.Groups[2].Value.Equals("free")?"FREE":data.Groups[3].Value);
        }
}
```

The actual pattern used:

```
"stock\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?shipping\":\"(\\$([\\d\\.]+)|(free))\\s?(.*?)\",\".*?finalPrice\":\"(.*?)\""
```

The Result line up:

```
Group #     Sample Data                         Notes
0           (whole string)                      [both]
1           In stock. Limit 5 per customer.     [both]
2           free/$19.99                         [free/with price]
3.          19.99                               [populated only for price]
4.          free                                [populated only for free]
5.          Shipping                            [both]
6.          139.99                              [both]
```

Sample output from above code:

```
Testing 'var rawItemInfo={"stock":"In stock. Limit 5 per customer.","shipping":"$19.99 Shipping","finalPrice":"139.99","itemInfo":"<div class="grpPricing"'
0. stock":"In stock. Limit 5 per customer.","shipping":"$19.99 Shipping","finalPrice":"139.99"
1. In stock. Limit 5 per customer.
2. $19.99
3. 19.99
4. 
5. Shipping
6. 139.99
Price is 19.99

Testing 'var rawItemInfo={"stock":"In stock. Limit 5 per customer.","shipping":"free Shipping","finalPrice":"139.99","itemInfo":"<div class="grpPricing"'
0. stock":"In stock. Limit 5 per customer.","shipping":"free Shipping","finalPrice":"139.99"
1. In stock. Limit 5 per customer.
2. free
3. 
4. free
5. Shipping
6. 139.99
Price is FREE
```

Comment: same comments as above answers i get syntax error "Unrecognized escape sequence" with ur answers too

Comment: @SOFUser: Please see my answer, I've updated it with working version, and posted code to a demo.

Comment: Remember! Shipping can be like this too `"shipping\":\"free Shipping\"`

Comment: Remember! Shipping can be like this too `"shipping\":\"free Shipping\"`

Comment: @SOFUser: Would you like to catch either or?

Comment: your solution work for free now but not for numbers  "stock\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?shipping\":\"(\\$[\\d\\.]+|free)\\s?(.*?)\",\".*?finalPrice\":\"(.*?)\"";

Comment: @SOFUser: I think i messed up the copy-paste. Check the ideone link for the specific pattern I use, this has been confirmed working and accurate.

Comment: yes i got ur answer almost complete but only one problem is that it is giving $19.99 while i wanted only 19.99

Comment: @SOFUser: Well, the bad part about breaking the price off solo is that when there is no price (i.e. "Free" is found)  you're going to get one fewer group match. You can alleviate this, however, by using named groups. I'll draw up another demo for you, just a second.

Comment: @SOFUser: Use http://www.ideone.com/lWVqN -- If `data.Groups[2].Value!="free"` the price is in `data.Groups[3].Value`, otherwise group 3 will be empty and group 4 will contain the word "Free" (this keeps the rest of the groups in order and consistent)

Answer (score 0):

You just need `\$?` at the right place in there:

`var regPattern = "stock\":\"(.*?)\",\".*?shipping\":\"\\$?(.*?) .*?\",\".*?finalPrice\":\"(.*?)\"";`

Comment: i already tried it but when u place \$ i get syntax error "Unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need to escape the \ in the string literal as well as the $ in the regex. Solution amended.

Comment: Remember! Shipping can be like this too `"shipping\":\"free Shipping\"`

Comment: Well, the $ needs to be optional then. Solution amended.

Comment: your solution now giving ... "19.99 shiping"

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you didn't want the entire thing. Solution amended.

Answer (score 0):

How about a general purpose solution?

```
string str = String.Concat(
    "var rawItemInfo={",
    string.Join(",", "\"stock\":\"In stock. Limit 5 per customer.\"",
                     "\"shipping\":\"$19.99 Shipping\"",
                     "\"finalPrice\":\"139.99\"",
                     "\"itemInfo\":\"<div class=\\\"grpPricing\\\" />\""),
    "}");

// recognize a JSON* object
var item = @"""(?<key>[^""]+)""\s*:\s*""(?<value>(?:[^\\""]|\\"")+)""";
var jsonRe = new Regex(@"\{\s*" + item + @"(?:\s*,\s*" + item + @")*\s*\}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var m = jsonRe.Match(str);

// build the corresponding dictionary
var json = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary();
if (m.Success)
{
    int captures = m.Groups["key"].Captures.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < captures; i++)
    {
        json[m.Groups["key"].Captures[i].Value] = m.Groups["value"].Captures[i].Value;
    }
}

// get the values
var val1 = json["stock"];       // "In stock. Limit 5 per customer."
var val2 = json["shipping"];    // "$19.99 Shipping"
var val3 = json["finalPrice"];  // "139.99"

// extract price from val2
val2 = Regex.Replace(val2, @"(?:\$(\d+\.\d{2})|(free)) Shipping", @"$1"); // "19.99"
```

<sub>* p.s., "JSON" is the right term for it right?</sub>

Comment: Of course this will fail for anything where the values are not strings wrapped in double-quotes.